# Where do Ark of Truth and Covenant fit into the Stargate series?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I was wondering where Stargate: The Ark of Truth & Covenant fit into Stargate.

Are these movies or in the series?

Comment: [Covenant](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Covenant) was an episode from Season 8. You mean [Stargate: Continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate:_Continuum)

Answer (score 7):

***[Stargate: Ark of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate:_The_Ark_of_Truth)*** and ***[Stargate: Continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate:_Continuum)*** (not Covenant) follow directly on from the final episode of Stargate SG-1.

Unless you've watched the bulk of Season 10 of Stargate SG-1 and especially the series finale; [SG-1: *Unending*](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Unending), the major themes of these two made-for-tv films will make little sense to you and will extensively spoil the final season.